How to write into curl's ERRORBUFFER inside CURLOPT_READFUNCTION function?
I use curl in a C++ project to upload a file to a service. Since we use our internal company framework classes for reading files we define a READFUNCTION for that. The internal function can throw an exception so I wanted to catch that.
My first thought was to put a try-catch around curl_easy_perform but I am not sure if that will work.
Instead I read how curl does error handling and I found the ERRORBUFFER. But how to I access it?
// inside some other function
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, (char*) curlErrorBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data_from_file);


// the READFUNCTION
size_t read_data_from_file(char* buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, File* file) {
  size_t nread = 0;
  try {
    nread = file->read(buffer, size * nitems);
  }
  catch (ReadError &e) {
    nread = CURL_READFUNC_ABORT;
    // How to write to ERRORBUFFER?
    // strncpy(ERRORBUFFER, "Failed to read file, " + e.msg, BUF_SIZE);
  }
  return nread;
}

Is there any way to access the ERRORBUFFER without making it global? Would using try-catch around curl_easy_perform work too?

To handle exceptions in your READFUNCTION and ensure proper error reporting through ERRORBUFFER, you can use the following approach:

Using CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER: This sets a buffer where libcurl stores human-readable error messages. You need to make sure this buffer is accessible to your READFUNCTION.

Using CURLOPT_READFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READDATA: You can pass a pointer to a struct that contains both your file pointer and the error buffer to the READFUNCTION.

Error Handling in READFUNCTION: Catch exceptions in your READFUNCTION, set the appropriate error message in the error buffer, and return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT to abort the operation.


Here's how you can implement this:

Define a struct to hold the file pointer and the error buffer:
struct FileContext {
    File* file;
    char* errorBuffer;
};


Modify your READFUNCTION to use this struct:
size_t read_data_from_file(char* buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void* userdata) {
    FileContext* context = static_cast<FileContext*>(userdata);
    size_t nread = 0;
    try {
        nread = context->file->read(buffer, size * nitems);
    }
    catch (const ReadError &e) {
        nread = CURL_READFUNC_ABORT;
        if (context->errorBuffer) {
            std::strncpy(context->errorBuffer, e.what(), CURL_ERROR_SIZE - 1);
            context->errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Ensure null-termination
        }
    }
    return nread;
}


Set up your CURL options to use this struct:
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    char curlErrorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    FileContext context;
    context.file = &yourFile;  // Your File object
    context.errorBuffer = curlErrorBuffer;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrorBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data_from_file);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &context);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CURL error: %s\n", curlErrorBuffer);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}



Explanation

Struct FileContext: This struct holds the file pointer and the error buffer, ensuring both are accessible within the READFUNCTION.
read_data_from_file Function: This function casts the userdata to FileContext, uses the file pointer to read data, and handles exceptions by writing the error message to the error buffer.
CURL Options: The error buffer and the FileContext struct are set via CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, and CURLOPT_READDATA.

Notes

Error Buffer Size: CURL_ERROR_SIZE is the predefined size of the error buffer used by libcurl.
Null-Termination: Ensure the error message is null-terminated to prevent buffer overflows.
Return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT: This signals libcurl to abort the operation when an exception occurs.

By structuring your code this way, you avoid the need to make the error buffer global, encapsulating the file and error handling logic within a single struct passed to libcurl.

While technically correct, if you go this route then there is really no point in using CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER since you have direct access to the char[] buffer in both the read function and the caller of curl_easy_perform() (in which case, I would use a std::string instead). CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER is meant for liburl to write its own error messages into, not for writing user-defined errors into.

Good point. We have some conditions, maybe we use it on some parts I have not yet found.
